# Qt Designer crashes using QWebEngineView

Tags: qt-designer, qwebengineview

Qt Designer (5.11.2) crashes on selecting the QWebEngineView-Widget.

I am creating a dialogform for including it in QGIS 3 as .ui file. In the form I want to display a website by using the QWebEngineView.

Sadly I am not able to drag the widget inside the dialog window, because Qt Designer crashes instantly on clicking the QWebEngineView button. The issue appears with Qt Designer provided with QGIS 3.3.0 as well as QGIS 3.2.3.

In the Windows Event Viewer I get the errorcode 0xC0000022.
Is someone stuggling with the same issue and has any ideas for solving it?

Comment: There is no point in reporting this here. It looks like a QGIS issue, so you need to report it on [their bug tracker](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues).

Comment: the problem appears in Qt Designer itself, before importing or using it in QGIS, so for me it has nothing to do with QGIS

Comment: To quote from your question: "The issue appears with Qt Designer provided with QGIS". So, yes, it is very relevant. The latest version of Qt Designer is 5.12.3, so clearly they need to upgrade (or you do).

Comment: Due to permission restrictions I am not able to upgrade the Qt Designer. Furthermore I am not sure whether that's a classic bug for reporting to the QGIS bug tracker. For me the problem seems to be somewhere else

Comment: There is no such issue in version 5.12.3 of Designer as provided by Qt. If the issue persists in the latest version of QGIS, then it is clearly a QGIS-specific bug. If you can't upgrade QGIS, use the latest official version of Qt Designer instead.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Actually I found an active QGIS [issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30065)  on Github which describes exactly that problem. So hopefully it will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

I do have the same issue without any use i know about qgis,
Only qtdesigner, that instantly crashes when clicking qtwebs..Ico

Looking everywhere for it, i don't find anything clear.
Bad installs
Missing files
Conflits between envs...

I do have:
Ubuntu 20.04
Python 3.9.9 with classic idle
Qt 5.12.2
Pyqt5 as installed with apt-get
(Even qtwebengine, cause i couldn't install or compile simple in any other without a strong internet connection)